# .htaccess correct way to redirect from one Wordpress instance to another?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

First, I am sorry if there are similar threads, but I cannot figure out what is the right approach for the following problem:

I cannot figure out, how to properly change my .htaccess files, so that the following conditions will work:

I have 2 independent WordPress instances under one domain. (Lets say: example.com)

- **Old instance** is hosted here: **example.com/old/**
- **New instance** is hosted here: **example.com/new/**

**Current behaviour when i access example.com:**

- When I access example.com, it redirects to the old instance.
  Browser is showing: example.com/old

**Desired behaviour, when i access example.com:**

- It Redirects to example.com/new/
- Hides the subfolder path (/new) from the url, so that in the address bar only example.com is visible (or any other part except the /new/) in the middle.

My first approach was to add the following line in the /old/.htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.com/new/
```

But then, it redirected example.com to: example.com/new/old/ which resulted in a 404.
Since the .htaccess files look kind of identical in /old/ and /new/ I cannot figure out, where exactly is defined, that example.com/ is redirecting to /old/ by default.

Here are the .htaccess contents of each instance and root folder:

### .htaccess-content / (root)

```
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
```

### .htaccess-content /old/ (old instance)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
RewriteRule .* - [CO=wordpress_test_cookie:WP+Cookie+check:%{HTTP_HOST}:1440:/]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /old/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /old/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

### .htaccess-content /new/ (new instance)

```
#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /new/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /new/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
</IfModule>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `RewriteRule` in your `old/. htaccess` instead of using `Redirect` . A RewriteRule can map the request from your `old` directory to the `new` directory without a change in URL.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/new [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new/$1 [L]
```

This should go in htaccess in your `/root` directory and remember to put this at the top or before other rewriting directives.

Also change  "WordPress home URL" and "Site address" by going to `settings->general` in your WordPress dashboard.
You can use `https://example.com` as the WordPress home URL and `https://example.com/new` as your WordPress site address.

Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Thank you. I could fix this with your last paragraph. I just had also to overwrite the index.php in root with the Wordpress-specific index.php from /new/ and create a generic .htaccess file.